# cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type 'void (*)()'

Tags: c++, class, methods, function-pointers

I'm trying to dereference a method pointer stored in a static array and call it from within a method, but I'm getting the following error:

```
error: 'chip8::Chip8::table[0]' cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type 'void (*)()'
     (this->*table[0])();
                    ^
```

Here is my class declaration (chip.hpp):

```
class Chip8{
  private:
    static void (*table[16])(); //function pointer table
    //...
  public:
    void cycle();
    //...
};
```

and here are the implementations of Chip8::cycle and Chip8::table (chip.cpp):

```
void (Chip8::*table[16])() = {
    &Chip8::opcode0,
    &Chip8::JP_1nnn,
    &Chip8::CALL_2nnn,
    &Chip8::SE_3xkk,
    &Chip8::SNE_4xkk,
    &Chip8::SE_5xy0,
    &Chip8::LD_6xkk,
    &Chip8::ADD_7xkk,
    &Chip8::opcode8,
    &Chip8::SNE_9xy0,
    &Chip8::LD_Annn,
    &Chip8::JP_Bnnn,
    &Chip8::RND_Cxkk,
    &Chip8::DRW_Dxyn,
    &Chip8::opcodeE,
    &Chip8::opcodeF
  };

  void Chip8::cycle(){
    opcode = (memory[pc] << 8) | memory[pc+1];
    pc+=2;

    (this->*table[0])(); // error here

    if(dt > 0){
      dt--;
    }

    if(st > 0){
      st--;
    }
  }
```

EDIT:
Here are the declarations of the functions assigned to the table:

```
//Function table extensions
    void opcode0();
    void opcode8();
    void opcodeE();
    void opcodeF();

    //Instructions
    void CLS_00E0();  // Clears screen
    void RET_00EE();  // Pops new pc off the stack
    void JP_1nnn();   // Jumps to nnn
    void CALL_2nnn(); // Pushes current pc to stack and jumps to nnn
    void SE_3xkk();   // Skip next instruction if Vx = kk
    void SNE_4xkk();  // Skip next instruction if Vx != kk
    void SE_5xy0();   // Skip next instruction if Vx == Vy
    void LD_6xkk();   // Set Vx = kk
    void ADD_7xkk();  // Vx += kk
    void LD_8xy0();   // Vx = Vy
    void OR_8xy1();   // Vx |= Vy
    void AND_8xy2();  // Vx &= Vy
    void XOR_8xy3();  // Vx ^= Vy
    void ADD_8xy4();  // Vx += Vy, if the sum is greater than 255, then VF = 1
    void SUB_8xy5();  // Vx -= Vy, if Vx > Vy, then VF = 1, otherwise VF = 0
    void SHR_8xy6();  // Vx >>= 1, if least significant bit of Vx is 1, then VF is set to 1, otherwise 0
    void SUBN_8xy7(); // Vx = Vy - Vx, if Vy > Vx, VF = 1, otherwise VF = 0
    void SHL_8xyE();  // Vx <<= 1, if most significant bit of Vx is 1, then VF is set to 1, otherwise 0
    void SNE_9xy0();  // Skip next instruction if Vx != Vy
    void LD_Annn();   // I = nnn
    void JP_Bnnn();   // Jumps to nnn + V0
    void RND_Cxkk();  // Vx = random byte & kk
    void DRW_Dxyn();  // Draws n-byte (n = height) sprite starting at Vx and Vy. If collision detected, VF = 1
    void SKP_Ex9E();  // Skip next instruction if value of Vx is pressed
    void SKNP_ExA1(); // Skip next instruction if value of Vx isn't pressed
    void LD_Fx07();   // Set Vx = delay timer
    void LD_Fx0A();   // Wait for key press and store value in Vx
    void LD_Fx15();   // Set delay timer = Vx
    void LD_Fx18();   // Set sound timer = Vx
    void ADD_Fx1E();  // Set I += Vx
    void LD_Fx29();   // Set I = memory location of digit sprite in Vx
    void LD_Fx33();   // Store BCD representation of value of Vx in I, I+1, I+2
    void LD_Fx55();   // Store registers V0 through Vx (including) starting at memory location I
    void LD_Fx65();   // Read registers V0 through Vx (including) starting at memory location I
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like `opcode0` et al are non-static member functions. In this case, the type of `Chip8::opcode0` is `void (Chip::*)()`, not `void (*)()`. Your `table` stores the wrong type to begin with; you should see a compiler error where it's initialized. Make it something like `using OpType = void (Chip::*)(); static OpType table[16];` (for readability, if nothing else).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so how exactly should I change my code?

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TY6rrceKT)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm now getting this error: chip8.o:chip8.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN5chip85Chip85tableE[.refptr._ZN5chip85Chip85tableE]+0x0): undefined reference to `chip8::Chip8::table'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You are not linking with the source file where `table` is defined. Check build configuration. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik All of the methods referenced in the table array are also defined in chip.hpp and implemented in chip.cpp, and they aren't causing any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that when you wrote:

```
static void (*table[16])();
```

you're declaring a **static data member** named `table` that is an *array of size `16` whose elements are pointers to **free function** with no parameter and return type of int*.

But what you actually want is a `table` that is an *array of size `16` whose elements are pointers to the **member functions** of `Chip8`* which you can do as shown below:

```
class Chip8{
  private:
//---------------vvvvvvvv------------>note the added Chip8::* indicating that a pointer to a member function instead of free function            
    static void (Chip8::*table[16])(); //function pointer table
  
  public:
    void cycle();
    void opcode0();
    
   
};
//definition for the static data member `table`
void (Chip8::*Chip8::table[16])() = {
    &Chip8::opcode0,
    
  };
void Chip8::opcode0()
{
    std::cout<<"opcode0 called"<<std::endl;
}
void Chip8::cycle(){
  
    std::cout<<"cycle called"<<std::endl;
    (this->*table[0])();
    
  }

int main()
{
    Chip8 chip;
    chip.cycle();
    return 0;
}
```

[Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/cSsjPHl-Cv).

---

Note that you can make the above code more **readable** using *alias declaration* as shown below:

```
class Chip8{
  private:
    using type = void (Chip8::*)();              
    static type table[16]; //function pointer table
  
  public:
    void cycle();
    void opcode0();
    
   
};
Chip8::type Chip8::table[16] = {
    &Chip8::opcode0,
    
  };
void Chip8::opcode0()
{
    std::cout<<"opcode0 called"<<std::endl;
}
void Chip8::cycle(){
  
    std::cout<<"cycle called"<<std::endl;
    (this->*table[0])();
    
}
int main()
{
    Chip8 chip;
    chip.cycle();
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/-3U_T-nDb)

Answer (score 1):

Your table contains function pointers, not member function pointer. Just use them as function pointers without `this`.

My guess is all the functions assigned to the table are static functions.

---

For non static function use a member function pointer type for the table:

```
static void (Chip::*table[16])(); // member function pointer table
```

or more readable:

```
using OpType = void (Chip::*)();
static OpType table[16];
```

Comment: I've just added the declarations of the methods. They aren't static members.

Comment: Then why don't you get an error or at least pointer conversion warning when you create the table?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps it is because I'm declaring the table in chip.hpp and implementing it in chip.cpp?

Comment: `static void ((Chip::*)table[16])();` looks invalid. It's spelled `static void (Chip::*table[16])();`.